# Drag'nDrop plugin for jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

Is there any drag'n'drop plugins which looks like this: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/inettuts/ but also can remember block position after draging in cookies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this

http://devheart.org/articles/jquery-customizable-layout-using-drag-and-drop/

Here is the [demo](http://devheart.org/examples/jquery-customizable-layout-using-drag-and-drop/2-saving-and-loading-items/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can take a look at [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/)

Answer (score 0):

The best drag and drop implementation I've seen is the sortable class in BBC's Glow library

see it working here: [Sortable - glow](http://www.bbc.co.uk/glow/docs/1.7/furtherinfo/widgets/sortable/)